# JQuery : doesn work javascript files after use load method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I searched for this question a lot but did not get an answer...

I have an a tag and I want a `div` to be loaded in the partial view when clicked,
The code works fine, but there is a problem with the partial view. I have a JavaScript file in partial view that does not work at all.

```
 $('#v-pills-tab2-tab').click(function () {
        $('#js-newhorse').load(' #js-newhorse');

    });
```

html :

```
<div class="widget widget-bordered title-a" id="js-newhorse">
@if (userInfo == true)
{
    <span class="alert alert-danger d-block text-center">Not access!!</span>
}
else
{


    List<Tuple<Guid, string>> productions = await _scope.GetProductionsHorse();
    List<Tuple<Guid, string>> microchips = await _scope.GetMicrochipsHorse();
    List<Tuple<Guid, string>> Farsiname = await _scope.GetFaHorseName();
    List<Tuple<Guid, string>> colors = await _scope.GetColorsHorse();
    List<Race> Races = await _scope.GetRaces();


    <div class="widget-box">





        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <input class="js-checkcode" type="checkbox">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group js-box-micro">
                    <div class="floating-label-group">
                        <select class="form-control selectmicro js-selected-code js-selected-item" id="select-mcode">
                            @foreach (var item in microchips)
                            {
                                <option value="@item.Item1">@item.Item2</option>
                            }
                        </select>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <input class="js-checkname" type="checkbox">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group js-box-name">
                    <div class="floating-label-group">
                        <select class="form-control selectname js-selected-name js-selected-item" id="select-name">
                            @foreach (var item in Farsiname)
                            {
                                <option value="@item.Item1">@item.Item2</option>
                            }
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>

        <form id="CreateHorse" method="post">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="floating-label-group">
                            <input type="text" maxlength="15" asp-for="MicrochipCode" autocomplete="off" class="form-control js-inputs">


                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="floating-label-group">
                            <input type="text" asp-for="FaName" autocomplete="off" class="form-control js-inputs">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="floating-label-group">
                            <input type="text" asp-for="EnName" autocomplete="off"  class="form-control js-inputs">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="floating-label-group">
                            <input type="text" asp-for="FaFatherHorseName" autocomplete="off" class="form-control js-inputs">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="floating-label-group">
                            <input type="text" asp-for="EnFatherHorseName" autocomplete="off"  class="form-control js-inputs">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="floating-label-group">
                            <input type="text" asp-for="FaMotherHorseName" autocomplete="off" class="form-control js-inputs">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="floating-label-group">
                            <input type="text" asp-for="EnMotherHorseName" autocomplete="off" class="form-control js-inputs">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="floating-label-group">
                            <select asp-for="Race" class="form-control js-inputs">
                                @foreach (var item in Races)
                                {
                                    <option value="@item.Id">@item.Title</option>
                                }
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="floating-label-group">
                            <select asp-for="ProductionId" class="form-control js-inputs">

                                @foreach (var item in productions)
                                {
                                    <option value="@item.Item1">@item.Item2</option>
                                }
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="floating-label-group">
                            <select asp-for="ColorId" class="form-control js-inputs">

                                @foreach (var item in colors)
                                {
                                    <option value="@item.Item1">@item.Item2</option>
                                }
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

               
            </div>

           

            <br style="clear: both;">
            <input type="submit" value="ثبت" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary pull-left btn-signin js-btninputs js-btn__mcode">
        </form>
    </div>

    <script src="~/site/js/select.js" defer></script>
    <script src="~/site/js/assest/js/horse.js" defer></script>
}
```

Can anyone find a solution to this problem?

Comment: From the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/load/): *"If `.load()` is called with a selector expression appended to the URL, however, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated, and thus are not executed."*

Comment: What script exactly is not being ran?

Comment: @JerdineSabio select2 script and my codes

Comment: @sunboy_sunboy please include everything; view, partial view, scripts, etc in your question

Comment: @sunboy_sunboy also the partial view code.

Comment: @JerdineSabio I changed my codes

Comment: @FelixKling You mean there is no way?

Comment: Probably not with `load` alone.